# Drag and Drop on views added to the Window Manager not working

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm updating an app of mine that has a draw-over-screen overlay of controls. At some point, drag and drop functionality stopped working (I question if it was even implemented right in the first place, but it still somehow works on Samsung). I have two views I add to the window manager when the overlay service starts (both views extend layout viewgroups):

```
mediaOverlay = new MediaOverlayView(this, getLayoutResource());
mediaOverlay.setOnClickListeners(this);

overlayDropView = new OverlayDropView(this);
overlayDropView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

windowManager.addView(overlayDropView, new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
));
windowManager.addView(mediaOverlay, layoutParams);
```

When the mediaOverlay view is long pressed, it starts the drag and shows the overlayDropView:

```
overlayDropView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
    //noinspection deprecation
    mediaOverlay.startDrag(null, new View.DragShadowBuilder(mediaOverlay), null, 0);
}
else {
    mediaOverlay.startDragAndDrop(null, new View.DragShadowBuilder(mediaOverlay), null, 0);
}
```

I set a drag listener for the overlayDropView in it's constructor:

```
setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();

        Log.d("Overlay", Integer.toString(action));

        if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
            Log.d("Overlay", "is dropped");
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Nothing ends up coming from it when overlayView is dropped onto overlayDropView. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. The key was reading more carefully and noticing this line in the [Drag and Drop docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) (emphasis mine):

> During the drag operation, the system dispatches drag events to the drag event listeners of the View objects **in the current layout**.

The two views added to the window manager should not have been able to interact normally due to this (which makes sense), I guess it working previously was a bug or the intended behavior changed at some point. Fixed it by re-evaluating the way I set up my views.

Why it was still working on current Samsung devices? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, then I came across the function call `startDragAndDrop()` of `View` class, use this function call with `View.DRAG_FLAG_GLOBAL` flag, now I am able to listen the drag and drop of other views.

Comment: Attention: This is simply beautiful but does only work on API 24+